# Не нужный перенос элемента флекс-контейнера в IE 11

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox

Имеется флекс-контейнер. И прекрасно отображается в браузерах, кроме IE 11. Там почему-то последний элемент он выносит на следующую строку. Как с этим справится? Пробовала задавать значения flex специально для IE с помощью символа "//", но никаких реакций.

CSS

```
.box {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
justify-content: flex-start;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto 3em;
}
.box__item {
position: relative;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-align-items: stretch;
align-items: stretch;
text-align: center;
-webkit-flex: 0 0 260px;
flex: 0 0 260px;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
margin:inherit;
}
```

Comment: ссылка http://caniuse.com/#search=flex как-бы намекает, что в ИЕ11 нормально работать не будет, т.к. поддержка частичная и присутствует много багов

Comment: `flex-wrap: wrap;` - зачем это писать, если переноса быть не должно?

Comment: @Qwertiy перенос осуществляется на маленьких экранах

Comment: @Alla, ну так помести его в media-запрос?

Comment: @Qwertiy в данном случае wrap выглядит гораздо лучше. Потому что на IE, если задать nowrap, он последний элемент контейнера на половину обрезает, словно он не вмещается

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте явно задать элементам внутри флекса width и свойствa flex-grow, flex-shrink и flex-basis:

```
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: ширина элемента;
```

Дело в том, что IE по умолчанию ставит `flex-grow: 1`, а остальные браузеры `flex-grow: 0` (со шринком наоборот), вследствие чего элементы всегда укладываются в один ряд, если это не указать принудительно. В трех словах flex-grow - на сколько элемент может растянуться относительно остальных, flex-shrink - как сильно он будет жаться относительно остальных, и basis - его базовая ширина. Вот тут есть подробнее с примером использования [туториал по флексу](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/)

Ваш код надо немного подправить, надо еще width добавить в итемы, затем, элементы внутри флекс контейнера не обязательно делать с display flex:

```
.box {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
justify-content: flex-start;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto 3em;
}
.box__item {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
-webkit-flex: 0 0 260px;
flex: 0 0 260px;
width: 260px;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
margin:inherit;
}
```

Comment: пробовала,но никак не реагирует

Comment: Вы не могли бы запостить эту часть кода, так будет проще разобраться.

Comment: добавила CSS в каком он виде сейчас к вопросу

Comment: обновил ответ с учетом этого

Comment: Увы, та же самая картина